# Making synchronous call asynchronous in C++

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, client-server

Here's the situation. Client is developed in java and server is in C++ (Windows platform). The communication happens using service calls in request and response fashion. But the calls are synchronous. Client makes a request call, server processes the request and sends the response. Till that time client is blocked.

There is provision of tasks which can be used to report the progress in client UI. That eliminates need to client waiting for response from server.

My initial take on this problem is, make a separate thread in detached mode. Send response to client that your request is taken. Spawn a task in the thread which will keep reporting the progress in UI.

The question is however, is this the best approach in long run? Or there should be a ground-up work to attain the async-nirvana?

Comment: How do you keep track of progress? Through a seperate callback? Or is that one big task is split into many small tasks which are counted?

Comment: @Fildor At server side, I spawn a task object which is framework supported and it shows the progress using it's progress update method.

Comment: OK, then you could make use of ExecutorService and Callables ...

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern these days seems to be to run the blocking IO in a separate thread, and then using callbacks/observers that run on the main thread. This patterns mixes well with the modern best practice of running all GUI work on the main thread.

EDIT:

Sorry, missed that the server is in C++.

To clarify...

On the client side you'd have two threads. The main thread for GUI and interaction, and a communications thread that was spawned when the connection was made. The two threads would communicate using some variant of the observer design pattern, meaning either "callbacks" or an actual observer. This allows the main thread to continue without freezing the GUI. Make sure that when the communications thread calls, the call is dispatched to the main thread somehow.

On the server side you will usually have some variant of the same pattern. There will be a master thread that listens for connections, and then spawns a thread (or process) for each connection that is created. The communications thread will the live as long as the session does. This allows the communications threads to do blocking calls without keeping the main thread from accepting new connections.

It's the same idea, really.

There are many variants, especially for the server side. The point is usually to conserve resources and avoid re-doing work, so you want to limit the number of threads allowed, and you probably want to re-use them ("thread pool").

As to exactly HOW to do it in C++, this is not an easy question to answer. Modern languages like C# and Java have a well-defined way of doing this, but C++ is agnostic in this regard. There is no "C++" answer, but there will be a "C++ on Windows" answer. Not being a Windows guy, I can't really help you here.

Comment: @DivyangPatel Client side. You'd need a complete different architecture and API if you want to introduce asynchronous server calls.